# SVN and SSH issues

Tags: svn, ssh, svn-checkout

I have an issue when I try to do the svn checkout.

I issued the following command on my  ubuntu linux box.

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://example.com/var/svn/site/trunk
```

But I am facing the following error:

```
ssh: FATAL: Illegal -o parameter "ControlMaster=no"
```

svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific to get proper help.

Comment: Can you SSH to the site example.com itself? SSH should work before svn+ssh will work.

Comment: No i couldn't do the SSH over there..... i haven't have a username and password for that yet... i guess the SVN copy available under public access mode....

Comment: To use the `ControlMaster` option you need OpenSSH version 4 at least, maybe you have an older version installed. You can test using `ssh -v`

Comment: Hi steve , when i type ssh -V. The get the following output ..

ssh: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu

Is the a higher version?

Answer (score 2):

Like Steve mentioned, this error is most likely due to OpenSSH lower than version 4.

Also seems like your ~/.subversion/config file contain the following section.

[tunnels]
ssh = ssh -o ControlMaster=no

The section is required to get access to SVN over SSH, but the options for controlmaster would only work for OpenSSH4 or above.

HTH,

Comment: my OpenSSH version : OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu ............. Is that a lower version i have on my machine